# How can I get IOBluetoothDevice's battery level, using Swift and AppKit (Xcode for MacOS)

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, appkit

I am using **Xcode** to develop a **MacOS app**, based on **Cocoa** & **AppKit**, written in **Swift**.

I am using [IOBluetoothDevice](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/iobluetooth/iobluetoothdevice) objects throughout my app, and I want to be able to display the devices' battery levels, if accessible.

I expect that devices which battery levels are visible on the OS's Bluetooth settings (see image below), to be also accessible programmatically (e.g., AirPods, Magic Keyboard, etc.). However, I could not find this anywhere.

I have also thought about executing a terminal command and found [this thread](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/215256/check-the-battery-level-of-connected-bluetooth-headphones-from-the-command-line), but it did also not work.

Thanks

[image: Bluetooth device battery level available to the OS]

Comment: don't see anyone else looking for this, but that what I found as private api https://github.com/w0lfschild/macOS_headers/blob/86427703608aa25521e57d8082f00a2db39af39b/macOS/Frameworks/IOBluetooth/6.0.2f2/IOBluetoothDevice.h#L306

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can get the battery level of Bluetooth devices from the IORegistry with IOKit.

This is a simple example to get the battery level for the Magic Trackpad 2

```
import IOKit

var serialPortIterator = io_iterator_t()
var object : io_object_t
let port: mach_port_t
if #available(macOS 12.0, *) {
    port = kIOMainPortDefault // New name in macOS 12 and higher
} else {
    port = kIOMasterPortDefault // Old name in macOS 11 and lower
}
let matchingDict : CFDictionary = IOServiceMatching("AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService")
let kernResult = IOServiceGetMatchingServices(port, matchingDict, &serialPortIterator)

if KERN_SUCCESS == kernResult {
    repeat {
        object = IOIteratorNext(serialPortIterator)
        if object != 0, let percent = IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperty(object, "BatteryPercent" as CFString, kCFAllocatorDefault, 0).takeRetainedValue() as? Int {
            print(percent)
            break
        }
    } while object != 0
    IOObjectRelease(object)
}    
IOObjectRelease(serialPortIterator)
```

For other devices you have to replace `AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService` and `Trackpad2` with the appropriate values. You can display the entire IORegistry in Terminal.app with `ioreg -l`.

Comment: Thanks! Is the list of all possible device names is listed somewhere? Or how to tell if I have for example two gamepads of the same model connected (say they support battery reporting) that BatteryPercent relates to this particular gamepad?

Comment: No, it’s a lot of investigation and trial&error. For example in Terminal.app filter the lines containing *BatteryPercent* with `grep` or `awk` and find the tree node and the class of the enclosing object. And to distinguish the devices there are other properties like vendor or maybe a serial number.

Comment: I'm surprised that there's no better API tho, so you can subscribe to the batteryPercentChanged or something. I doubt that Bluetooth menu bar widget just checks BatteryPercent inside of the for loop every 5 seconds.

Comment: I'm sure there is an API to observe properties in IOReg. Pretty low-level C-callbacks

Comment: @meneroush I mean, the menu probably just queries the value when the submenu pops open. Why would it need to observe the value?

Comment: 2022: I get an error `Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value` where `let percent` is defined.

Comment: @ixany This could be fix by adding a `?` after `IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperty(_:_:_:)` to unwrap optional safely.

Comment: `let percent…` is optional bound, actually it cannot crash.

Comment: What if I want to get battery level on iOS devices? Can I still using the same code?

Comment: @TonyChen Certainly not, the question is about Bluetooth devices.

Comment: I mean getting the battery level of classic bluetooth accessories (not BLE) on an iOS app. Is that possible?

Comment: I don't know. Try it.

Answer (score 0):

Extending on @Vadian's answer and updated to run in 2023 - I did something like this where I stored all the devices battery information in a dictionary based on the UUID. I call this function as needed before showing the information in the UI:

```
@Published
var batteryStatus: [String: String] = [:]

@MainActor
private func updateBatteryStatuses() {
    var batteryStatus: [String: String] = [:]
    
    // ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59730707/9605061
    var serialPortIterator = io_iterator_t()
    var object : io_object_t
    let port: mach_port_t = kIOMainPortDefault // New name in macOS 12 and higher

    let matchingDict : CFDictionary = IOServiceMatching("AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService")
    let kernResult = IOServiceGetMatchingServices(port, matchingDict, &serialPortIterator)

    if KERN_SUCCESS == kernResult {
        repeat {
            object = IOIteratorNext(serialPortIterator)
            if let percent = IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperty(object, "BatteryPercent" as CFString, kCFAllocatorDefault, 0)?.takeRetainedValue() as? Int,
                let deviceAddress = IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperty(object, "DeviceAddress" as CFString, kCFAllocatorDefault, 0)?.takeRetainedValue() as? String{
                batteryStatus[deviceAddress] = "\(percent)%"
            }
        } while object != 0
        IOObjectRelease(object)
    }
    
    IOObjectRelease(serialPortIterator)
    
    self.batteryStatus = batteryStatus
}
```

This is nice because after this function is called the UI is updated automatically :)